# Text substitution using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, replace

I have two datasets. One contains text description and another that contains a table with two columns `from_value` and `to_value`.

The idea is to replace all occurrences of the word in the text description using the second data set.

I can identify 4 types of words from this second dataset:

1. Simple word substitution: `RPLCD -> REPLACED`
2. Multi string word substitution: `ALT BRK -> ALTERNATE BREAK`
3. Words with special character in them: `A/C -> AIRCRAFT` or `1-APU -> 1 APU`
4. Special characters removal: if I have `%` in the string I should delete it; same thing for `-` unless it's inside a word like `1-APU` (we replace the whole word)

I uploaded an example of my 2 data sets via Gdrive, here's the link:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HYFhKAqbYPIy0ekyj9xLSbk30YZwf8ZG?usp=sharing

My idea was to split first my second dataset into 2 dataframes, one with multi words and one with one word and special character, or to split into 3 dataframes, one with multi, one with solo word and one for special character, and to apply first the first dataframe, then the 2sd and in the end the special character removal, but it's not working.

Do you have a way to manage this type of subsitution ?

Here's my code:

```
import sys
import pyspark
import pandas_datareader
import re
import csv
import xlrd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime


from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas_datareader import data, wb
from pandas import *
from xlrd import open_workbook

## 1)read the source table (OI and description)
xls = ExcelFile("df1.xls")
df = xls.parse(xls.sheet_names[0])

## 2)remove the nan values from df
df = df.replace(np.nan, '')

## 3)read the subtitution table
xls1 = ExcelFile("df2.xls")
df1 = xls1.parse(xls1.sheet_names[0])
df1.drop(df1.columns[0],inplace=True,axis=1)

## 4)separate the subtitution table into 2 datasets
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=('FROM_VALUE', 'TO_VALUE'))
df4 = pd.DataFrame(columns=('FROM_VALUE', 'TO_VALUE'))

df5=[]
df6=[]      

for (idx, row) in df1.iterrows():
    if len(row.loc['FROM_VALUE'].split()) > 1: 
        df5.append([row.loc['FROM_VALUE'],row.loc['TO_VALUE']])
    else:
        df6.append([row.loc['FROM_VALUE'],row.loc['TO_VALUE']])

df7= pd.DataFrame(df5)
df7=df7.rename(columns = {0:'FROM_VALUE',1:'TO_VALUE'})
df7 = df7.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
df9 = Series(df7.TO_VALUE.values,index=df7.FROM_VALUE).to_dict()


df8= pd.DataFrame(df6)
df8=df8.rename(columns = {0:'FROM_VALUE',1:'TO_VALUE'})
df8 = df8.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
df10 = Series(df8.TO_VALUE.values,index=df8.FROM_VALUE).to_dict()


## 5)processing the description list based on the subtitution table
df11 = {r'(\b){}(\b)'.format(k):r'\1{}\2'.format(v) for k,v in df9.items()}
df12 = {r'(\b){}(\b)'.format(k):r'\1{}\2'.format(v) for k,v in df10.items()}

df['WORK_PERFORMED_NEW'] = df['WORK_PERFORMED'].replace(df11, regex=True)
df['WORK_PERFORMED_NV'] = df['WORK_PERFORMED_NEW'].replace(df12, regex=True)
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that doesn't require downloading datasets from google drive

Comment: `import pandas as pd; from pandas import DataFrame; from pandas import *` and later `df3 = pd.DataFrame` sooner or later you're gonna regret this

Comment: @bobrobbob not sure to understand you reply !!!

Comment: @Mouad just use: `import pandas as pd`

Comment: @OferSadan here's an example of the subtitution table dataset: id From value         ->            to value
 A/C    ->                                                    Aircraft, 
1-B   ->                                                     1 B, 
"%"  -> "" ,
BRK     ->                                                  BRAKE, 
ALT BRK  ->                                             ALTERNATIVE BRAKE

Comment: @OferSadan for dataset 1 (source data); here's 3 rows sample:   WORD1 ! ? WORD2 <  : ) ALT WORD3 A/C DEFFRED WORD5 WORD6 , 1-APU WORD2 ~ REPLACED % WORD3 @ DEF WORD4 ALT WORD5 , WORD1 WORD2 ALT BRK WORD3 WORD4

Comment: @Mouad you import often the same object multiple times, pandas was just an example. if your project uses multiple files you'll end up in a circular import conundrum. be sure to import only what you want and avoid star imports

Answer (score 0):

I would split the substitution of words from the substitution of special characters, because IMO for the words you need to loop through your list, special characters can be replaced in one line.

So given are the following three variables, where `df1` is the data to be processed, `df2` is the word substitution list and `unwanted_chars` is a regex to filter characters:

```
df1
Out: 
                                       WORK_PERFORMED
ID                                                   
1   WORD1 ! ? WORD2 <  : ) ALT WORD3 A/C DEFFRED W...
2   1-APU WORD2 ~ REPLACED % WORD3 @ DEF WORD4 ALT...
3                     WORD1 WORD2 ALT BRK WORD3 WORD4

df2
Out: 
       FROM_VALUE         TO_VALUE
ROW_ID                            
1             DEF         DEFERRED
2         DEFERED         DEFERRED
3         DEFFRED         DEFERRED
4           DEFRD         DEFERRED
5           DFR D         DEFERRED
6            DFRD         DEFERRED
7         DIFERED         DEFERRED
8         ALT BRK  ALTERNATE BREAK
9             ALT         ALTITUDE
10            A/C         AIRCRAFT
11          A/BRK        AUTOBRAKE
12            BRK            BREAK
13         1-FIRE           1 FIRE
14           1-HP  1 HIGH PRESSURE

unwanted_chars = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+')
```

Then you can define a function which accepts a string as input and then loops over your substution list, checking for every entry trying to replace. This is done with a regex containing look arounds for spaces or beginning/end of string, so that no substring of a word is matched. After the loop a single line substitutes all unwanted characters by a space:

```
def subst(x):
    for fr, to in zip(df2.FROM_VALUE, df2.TO_VALUE):
        x = re.sub('((?<=^)|(?<= ))' + fr + '(?=$| )', to, x)
    x = re.sub(unwanted_chars, ' ', x)
    return x
```

Having that prepared, you would just have to map this function to the column of your dataframe:

```
df1.WORK_PERFORMED.map(subst)
Out: 
ID
1    WORD1     WORD2        ALTITUDE WORD3 AIRCRAFT...
2    1 APU WORD2   REPLACED   WORD3   DEFERRED WORD...
3              WORD1 WORD2 ALTERNATE BREAK WORD3 WORD4
Name: WORK_PERFORMED, dtype: object
```